# On delete set... not null?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of users, which includes a column referencing their location in the game.

I have a table of locations.

I have a foreign key tying the two together.

I want to make it so that if and when a location is deleted, users are sent to the nearest location - I can easily determine which location to send the user to with a simple lookup, but what I need to know is where can I put this trigger?

If I set the foreign key to "ON DELETE SET NULL", can I then use a trigger to detect the location being set to NULL and using `old.location` to determine where to send them? Is that a thing?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on your `locations` table, something like the following:

```
create trigger move_users
before delete
on locations
for each row
  update users
    set locationid = (select nearest from nearest where locationid = old.locationid)
  where locationid = old.locationid
```

Here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d60d/1) with some example data.